# Find all file with same extension, cp to new directory

Tags: find, cp

I have files with the extension .fastq.gz in multiple subdirectories.

I would like to copy all of these files into one new directory.

I tested with the following command, which seemed to work.

```
$find . -name \*.fastq.gz -exec ls {} \;
```

However, the following command didn't copy my files:

```
$find . -name \*.fastq.gz -exec cp {} newdirectory \;
```

Thanks for any help; I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find /home/path/ -name *.out -exec cp -R '{}' /home/path1/ \;
```